# Removing duplicate numbers from an array using a dictionary

Tags: vba, excel

I have created an array and would like to filter out any duplicates and be left with a new array with only the numbers that appeared once.

Below is my code. The first array captures all the numbers I need, but for some reason the second array is not filtering out as required and prints the same numbers as the first. Any help with finding the problem is greatly appreciated!

```
ReDim theArray(0 To dRange)
Dim singleValues()

Dim i
Dim q

'fill the array
For i = LBound(theArray) To UBound(theArray)
    If (dRange - (dRange * i) <= dRange) Then
        theArray(i) = (dHigh - (tSize * i))
    End If
Next

'filter repeating elements
 With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    'count each number qty
    For i = 0 To dRange
        .Item(theArray(i)) = .Item(theArray(i)) + 1
    Next
    'remove repeating
    For Each q In .Keys()
        If .Item(q) > 1 Then .Remove q
    Next
    'retrieve array
    singleValues = .Keys()
End With

Debug.Print Join(theArray)
Debug.Print Join(singleValues)
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, a [dictionary structure does not support key repetition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/dictionary-object) and is strongly against it:

> Each item is associated with a unique key. The key is used to retrieve an individual item and is usually a integer or a string, but can be anything except an array.

What you are probably trying to do is to increment the value of the key.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    'Microsoft Scripting Runtime Library
    Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary 
'or Dim dict as CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Dim arr1 As Variant
    Dim arr2 As Variant
    arr1 = Array(1, 11, 11, 112, 34, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7)

    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(arr1) To UBound(arr1)
        If Not dict.exists(arr1(i)) Then
            dict.Add arr1(i), 1
        Else    
            dict(arr1(i)) = dict(arr1(i) + 1)
        End If
    Next

    ReDim arr2(dict.Count)

    For i = 0 To dict.Count - 1
        Debug.Print dict.Keys(i); " key is value - "; dict.Items(i)
        arr2(i) = dict.Keys(i)
    Next i

    Debug.Print Join(arr1)
    Debug.Print Join(arr2)

End Sub
```

It prints the following two arrays:

```
1 11 11 112 34 5 6 6 7 7
1 11 12 112 34 5 6 7 8
```

I am not sure how you can use `With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")` and `Keys` together, because the syntax for assigning keys look like this: `dict(arr1(i))`, thus there is no point and you cannot refer to the With-Object. Still, there could be a workaround.

The code above uses Early binding, thus you have to add an MS library to it, it is quite faster on the long term.

Comment: And if the OP wouldn't want to have the keys where the count is > 1 (in your sample data, 6 or 7), they can simply add an if-statement for adding the keys to `arr2`.